# Basic Image display from Database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning the most basic of PHP MYSQL and am trying to display and image on my page along with Name, etc.
In the database I made a path: images/Paul.jpg alongside his first name and last name
Everything display as expected except for image. I have tried many iterations of the code but it either errors or displays a placeholder with no image or even on inspection doesnt show a path to the image directory.

Any thoughts?

```
    <?php echo $data['first_name']; ?> 
    <?php echo $data['last_name']; ?>
    <?php echo $data['age']; ?>
    <?php echo '<img src="['image']" />'; ?>        
    <?php echo $data['bio']; ?>
     
     
<?php 
} 
?> 
<!-- </table> -->
 <?php mysqli_close($db); // Close connection ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the path in your database, then you should use the path in the `src` attribute of your `img`

`<?php echo '<img src="' . $data['image'] . '" />'; ?>` 
You also need to make sure the directory with your image is at the same level as this file to display correctly or you'll get an incorrect path.

Comment: Thank you but I added that and now my next line is throwing an error: <?php echo $data['first_name']; ?> 
        <?php echo $data['last_name']; ?>
        <?php echo $data['age']; ?>
        <?php echo '<img src="images/' . $data['image'] . " />'; ?>
            
        <?php echo $data['bio']; ?>

Comment: i forgot a `'` after ` . $data['image'] . ` sorry. I edited my answer, could you try again ? also if you have any other errors, could you add them in your question, it makes them easier to see !

Comment: PERFECT!!!! You did it, thank you!